# How to read the date value in Excel General format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I am trying a read a date data "01FEB22" from a TSV file, and it read like in below screenshot,

[image]

I would like to read this date value in Excel General format as below,

[image]

44593 is the equivalent "General" format of the date value "01/02/2022". Is there a way to read the date value in General format in Power Query? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure the "01FEB22" must be converted to Date datatype first. (Will give you value like 01/02/2022)
Then add a custom column with this formula.

`= Number.ToText(Double.From([last_month]))`

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But is there a way to provide this formula like this `Table.TransformColumnTypes({"launch_month", type date, each Number.ToText(Double.From([last_month]))})`

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameHere",{{"ColumnNameHere", each Number.ToText(Double.From(Date.From(_)))  , type number}})

Comment: Does it work if this is the second step of the query? First step is the source